# Issue importing System.IO.File in .NET Core 3.1 API

Tags: c#, xml, api, asp.net-core

In a .net Core API, I have a Data Controller with a HttpPost endpoint that receives a json string from another web app.
This json string could contain 1 to 5 records consisting of an Id, a Description and a string of a base64 image.
I need to create a XML file  called Data.xml IF it doesn't exist already and populate it with the json string values.
I have seen examples such as:

```
XDocument document = new XDocument();

if(!File.Exists("MyXmlFile.xml")){
    //Populate with data here if necessary, then save to make sure it exists
    document.Save("MyXmlFile.xml");
}
else{
    //We know it exists so we can load it
    document.load("MyXmlFile.xml");
}
```

**File** is highlighted in red, and the using statement can't find the File namespace System.IO.File
I have also installed System.IO.FileSystem NuGet package, no luck either.
I have tried to do the same in a separate API I have also in NET Core 3.1 and I couldn't do this neither.
Does anyone have an idea what could be going wrong?

Controller code:

```
using aspnetcore_api_server.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO.File;

namespace aspnetcore_api_server.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class DataController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<DataModel> Get()
        {
            return null;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public List<DataModel> Post([FromBody] string records)
        {
            XDocument dataDocumentStorage = XDocument.Load("Data.xml");

            XDocument document = new XDocument();

            if (!File.Exists("Data.xml"))
            {
                //Populate with data here if necessary, then save to make sure it exists
                document.Save("Data.xml");
            }
            else
            {
                //We know it exists so we can load it
                //document.("Data.xml");
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: System.IO.File - you need a using statement for System.IO or fully qualify it

Comment: Can't find File if I fully set "using System.IO.File", typin the dot after System.IO doesn't display File as an option

Comment: I don't know why you are having this problem but I guarantee it is a thing in .NET Core. Maybe you were prompted by Visual Studio to generate a class and you accepted it and now you have your own System.IO namespace defined. Search your code for a file that defines it and delete it.

Comment: Could it be because it's an API and not a web app? I'm so lost, I tried to do the same in another api I have and same results... File doesn't show up.. I even installed the package System.IO.Filesystem and no banana either...

Comment: Side note: before claiming something "does not exist" please doublecheck if [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.exists?view=net-5.0#applies-to) say so (clearly not the case here). So the question needs a good [edit] to understand what is going on there.

Comment: @Tofetopo - `!File` should be `!File.Exists` -- it's a typo, so this post will likely be closed.

Comment: @Kit I can't even do File.Exists if File itself isn't working in the first place... I have updated that anyway

Comment: I've voted to reopen. The OP removed the typo, and this question has a very real, correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

[System.IO.File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=net-5.0) certainly exists as part of .NET Core and later, such as .NET 5.0.

The problems you are running into are

1. `using System.IO.File` is incorrect. You can't use a `using` directly on a type in C# unless you use a `using` with an alias or a `using static`
2. You're inheriting from `ControllerBase` which has a protected `File` method, and you're conflicting with that.

Change your implementation to

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Linq;

// here we alias the type System.IO.File to IoFile so it won't conflict
using IoFile = System.IO.File;

namespace aspnetcore_api_server.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class DataController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<DataModel> Get()
        {
            return null;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public List<DataModel> Post([FromBody] string records)
        {
            XDocument dataDocumentStorage = XDocument.Load("Data.xml");

            XDocument document = new XDocument();

            // here we use that type alias
            if (!IoFile.Exists("Data.xml"))
            {
                //Populate with data here if necessary, then save to make sure it exists
                document.Save("Data.xml");
            }
            else
            {
                //We know it exists so we can load it
                //document.("Data.xml");
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

This avoids the above two problems by using the alias.

Comment: I think the problem here is that this File.Exists check can't be done in a controller method, I have tried in a separate class and it works just fine. If I try to do that in the controller as I tried to do, I get the error "ContollerBase.File(byte[], string) is a method, which is not valid in the given context" - Not much I can do in the controller, not the end of the world though

Comment: Based on your coment, I've updated the answer.